# In what way does wait(NULL) work exactly in C?

Tags: c, fork, wait

If I use `wait(null)`, and I know (for sure) that the child will finish (exit) before we reach to `wait(null)` in the parent process, does the `wait(null)` block the parent process?

I mean, the `wait()` won't get any signal, right?

```
int main() {
    int pipe_descs[2];
    int i, n, p;

    srand(time(NULL(;
    pipe(pipe_descs);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid_t status = fork();

        if (status == 0) {
            n = rand() % 100;
            p = (int) getpid();

            write(pipe_descs[1], &n, sizeof(int));
            write(pipe_descs[1], &p, sizeof(int));
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            read(pipe_descs[0],  &n,  sizeof(int));
            read(pipe_descs[0],  &p,  sizeof(int));
            printf(" %d %d\n", n, p);
            wait(NULL); // (1)
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait): "If a child has already changed state, then these calls return immediately". or perhaps just run it under those conditions and see what happens?

Comment: In any case I can't think of any way to be certain that the child has terminated before the parent `wait()`s for it, except for the parent to handle `SIGCHLD` manually.  In particular, it is not safe to assume that that will always happen in your example code.

Comment: What is `null`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`wait(NULL)` will block the parent process until any of its children has finished. If the child terminates before the parent process reaches `wait(NULL)` then the child process turns to a *zombie process* until its parent waits on it and its released from memory.

If the parent process doesn't wait for its child, and the parent finishes first, then the child process becomes an orphan and is assigned to `init` as its child. And init will wait and release the process entry in the process table.

In other words: the parent process will be blocked until the child process returns an exit status to the operating system which is then returned to the parent process. If the child finishes before the parent reaches wait(NULL) then it will read the exit status, release the process entry in the process table and continue execution until it finishes as well.