# Why is wait necessary in double fork to remove zombie process?

Tags: c

I'm not sure to understand why do we need to call wait() in the parent to take care of zombie process when double forking is supposed to take care of it ? Why do we need to double fork if wait() alone can already do the job ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    // fork first time
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // double fork
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("Grandchild pid : %d\n Child"
                   " pid : %d\n",
                   getpid(), getppid());
        }
        else
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your original process doesn't wait for its child, its child becomes a zombie when it exits.  You have to wait to prevent the creation of the zombie.

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42426816/1256234) answer your question?

Comment: I understand why we need to wait() but I don't understand the use of double fork here, I've read that double fork is used to prevent the creation of zombie, but here even without the double fork the wait() call in the parent will already be preventing zombie and If I remove the wait() but keep the  double fork() I will have zombie process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure to understand why do we need to call wait() in the parent to take care of zombie process when double forking is supposed to take care of it ? Why do we need to double fork if wait() alone can already do the job ?

You misunderstand the purpose and usage of the double-`fork` idiom.

### Background

Every process except pid 1 becomes a zombie when it terminates.  The zombie persists in the process table until it is collected via one of the `wait`-family functions.  If the process's parent is still alive then that is the one that must `wait` to collect it.  Otherwise, the responsibility is transferred to process 1.  A viable choice of program to run as process 1 will handle those very efficiently, so you will almost never see zombies that are waiting for process 1 to collect them.

### Double `fork`ing

The point of a double `fork` is for the original process **A** to create a process that will be the responsibility of process 1 to clean up, despite **A** continuing to run.  A fire & forget it situation, if you will. This is accomplished by `fork`ing a child **B** that immediately `fork`s the wanted process, **C**.  Process **B** then terminates to transfer responsibility for **C** to process 1 (*not* process **A**).

*That does not relieve process **A** of its responsibility to `wait` for process **B***.  But **A** can perform that `wait` right away and know that it won't be delayed very long, as opposed to either blocking until **C** terminates, or having to periodically check for **C**'s completion, or leaving **C** as a zombie indefinitely, which would be the alternatives if **A** `fork`ed **C** directly.